# how to use octopus gem in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using octopus gem in my rails3 application.i added the below in my migration file,

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  using(:master, :slave1)
  def self.up
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :age

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

Below is my shards.yml file

```
## YAML Template.
---
octopus:
  environments:
    - development
  development:
    slave1:
      host: localhost
      adapter: mysql
      database: Octopus_development
```

Here slave1 database will be created by rails or do we need to create? Can anyone explain this? What should i do now?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the DB slave1 created before you run the migrations. The migration however will be run on both the master and the slave1.

Also you will prob have to setup slave1 as a replica of the master if you are going to use replication. If its only for sharding purpose then replication setup is not required.